# Example of abounded holomorphic function satisfying this particular condition

Tags: complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

This question was asked in my complex analysis quiz and I was unable to solve it . So I am asking for help here.

> Question: Give an example of a bounded holomorphic function f on $\mathbb{C}$/$\mathbb{R}$ which cannot be extended to a larger set.

I am sorry but I can't provide any meaningful and an attempt in the direction of this question as I am really confused by this peciluar question.

It is my humble request to help me with this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f = 1$ in the upper half plane and $f = -1$ in the lower half plane.

Comment: How would you prove that this cannot be extended to any larger set ? Which result will you use ?

Comment: Any larger set has a real say $r$. Note that $f(r) = 1$ by continuity from above and $f(r) = -1$ by continuity from below.